# How to escape html tags in Extjs?

Tags: javascript, extjs

I want to add some examples(see below) curl commands to show users how to do a certain action. The problem is I want to wrap it in a pre tag. So when I use the HTML tag I get the compiled pre tag but the "<>" disappear for '' because it thinks it's HTML. I need both the pre tags to work correctly en literally show the other parts wrapped in '<>'.

curl -XPOST --header "Content-Type: application/json" --data ""

```
cls: 'curl-example',
    bind: {
         html: '<pre>curl -XPOST --header "Content-Type: application/json" --data "<your json data>"</pre>'
}
```

This causes the opposite problem. The pre tag get literally printed.

```
cls: 'curl-example',
    bind: {
         text: '<pre>curl -XPOST --header "Content-Type: application/json" --data "<your json data>"</pre>'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Ext.htmlEncode() and Ext.htmlDecode() methods.